# Where do I find EF6.0 database mapping files?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I recently renamed my VS2013 Project and am getting the following error page.

> Server Error in '/' Application.
>
> Migrations is enabled for context 'ApplicationDbContext' but the
>   database does not exist or contains no mapped tables. Use Migrations
>   to create the database and its tables, for example by running the
>   'Update-Database' command from the Package Manager Console.
>
> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of
>   the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more
>   information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.InvalidOperationException: Migrations is
>   enabled for context 'ApplicationDbContext' but the database does not
>   exist or contains no mapped tables. Use Migrations to create the
>   database and its tables, for example by running the 'Update-Database'
>   command from the Package Manager Console.

**Source Error:**

Line 33:         {
Line 34:             if(User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
Line 35:             ViewBag.Email = UserManager.FindById(User.Identity.GetUserId()).Email;
Line 36:             bll.UpdateLogInStats("Index",User.Identity.GetUserName());
Line 37:             ViewBag.versionNumber = bll.GetSiteVersionNumber();

Source File: c:\Users\Evolution\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\CompleTrance\CompleTrance\Controllers\HomeController.cs    Line: 35

**Stack Trace:**

[InvalidOperationException: Migrations is enabled for context 'ApplicationDbContext' but the database does not exist or contains no mapped tables. Use Migrations to create the database and its tables, for example by running the 'Update-Database' command from the Package Manager Console.]
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.MigrationsChecker.IsMigrationsConfigured(InternalContext internalContext, Func`1 databaseExists) +147
   System.Data.Entity.CreateDatabaseIfNotExists`1.InitializeDatabase(TContext context) +193
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.<>c_*DisplayClasse`1.<CreateInitializationAction>b__d() +76
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.PerformInitializationAction(Action action) +60
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.PerformDatabaseInitialization() +337
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.<InitializeDatabase>b__4(InternalContext c) +7
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.RetryAction`1.PerformAction(TInput input) +110
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.InitializeDatabaseAction(Action`1 action) +198
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.InitializeDatabase() +73
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.GetEntitySetAndBaseTypeForType(Type entityType) +27
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.Initialize() +53
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.get_InternalContext() +15
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.FindAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken, Object[] keyValues) +18
   System.Data.Entity.DbSet`1.FindAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken, Object[] keyValues) +34
   System.Data.Entity.DbSet`1.FindAsync(Object[] keyValues) +13
   Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework.EntityStore`1.GetByIdAsync(Object id) +49
   Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework.UserStore`1.FindByIdAsync(String userId) +29
   Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.d*_a.MoveNext() +102
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) +93
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) +52
   Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.AsyncHelper.RunSync(Func`1 func) +159
   Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.UserManagerExtensions.FindById(UserManager`1 manager, String userId) +157
   CompleTranceServer.Controllers.HomeController.Index() in c:\Users\Evolution\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\CompleTrance\CompleTrance\Controllers\HomeController.cs:35
   lambda_method(Closure , ControllerBase , Object[] ) +62
   System.Web.Mvc.ActionMethodDispatcher.Execute(ControllerBase controller, Object[] parameters) +14
   System.Web.Mvc.ReflectedActionDescriptor.Execute(ControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 parameters) +157
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethod(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2 parameters) +27
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.b_*36(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ActionInvocation innerInvokeState) +22
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`2.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +29
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethod(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +32
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncInvocationWithFilters.b*_3c() +50
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c_*DisplayClass45.b*_3e() +225
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c_*DisplayClass30.b*_2f(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +10
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +10
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethodWithFilters(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +34
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c_*DisplayClass28.b*_19() +26
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c_*DisplayClass1e.b*_1b(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +100
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +10
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeAction(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +27
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.b_*1d(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ExecuteCoreState innerState) +13
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +36
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +54
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecuteCore(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +39
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.b*_15(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Controller controller) +12
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +28
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +54
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +29
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.System.Web.Mvc.Async.IAsyncController.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +10
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.b__4(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ProcessRequestState innerState) +21
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +36
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +54
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +31
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult result) +9
   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +9514812
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +155

Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.0.30319.18408

I believe the problem is that the db mapping file contains the old project name but I do not see anywhere that I can edit the mapping files to correct the problem.  I would rather not delete the database and recreate it and the suggested idea to run "update-database" did not work and gives me the following error.

> Cannot create file 'C:\Users\Evolution\Documents\Visual Studio
>   2013\Projects\CompleTrance\CompleTrance\App_Data\aspnet-CompleTranceServer-20131116015908.mdf'
>   because it already exists. Change the file path or the file name, and
>   retry the operation. CREATE DATABASE failed. Some file names listed
>   could not be created. Check related errors.

**Connection strings:**
Here are my connection strings.
   `<connectionStrings>
    <add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnet-CompleTranceServer-20131116015908.mdf;Initial Catalog=aspnet-CompleTranceServer-20131116015908;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
    <add name="AWSiteContext" connectionString="Data Source=(localdb)\v11.0; Initial Catalog=AWSiteContext-20140105010431; Integrated Security=True; MultipleActiveResultSets=True; AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|AWSiteContext-20140105010431.mdf" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>`

I don't recall why I named the context listed AWSiteContext.  The old name of my project was AncientWorld, so AW was the initials of the site name.  I have my IIS going to defaultConnection though so I'm not sure the AWSiteContext really does anything.  It isn't in the project anywhere else.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks.

Comment: Have you adjusted a connectionString in web.config?

Comment: Can you share you EF settings file?

Comment: Added connection strings and need to know where EF settings are to share them.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "EF settings". There's not really such a thing. Your migrations configuration is under Migrations/Configuration.cs, and then there's your DbContext subclass, wherever you created that.

Comment: My context key in the migrations configuration.cs file is the same as it is in the migration table data (renamed those earlier) so that isn't the issue.  I did a solution wide app name replace so all the code in the solution itself should be showing the new name.  The issue is in some hidden mapping file that is still retaining the old name.  It says in the error message that an assembly of the old name is conflicting with the new one's friendly name.  I just don't know the solution.

Comment: I decided to back up my database and delete it from my project and let EF6.0 create me a new one.  Everything worked perfectly and all my data was recreated.  I will leave this question open for anyone who wants to answer the topic question though as that might be useful for situations where my solution failed to work (if that ever happens)  :)  Love EF. :)  Thanks everyone for the input and formatting help.